# Notification Custom with ResetPassword Not Work

Tags: laravel

I have created a new Notification file for when certain account details are modified (username, password, email ...) to send a notification to the user informing of important changes to his account.

I have copied the ResetPassword Notification and customized it because I want the link that sends the user to the screen to retrieve the password.

The implementation works to a certain extent, the email is sent with a link that takes you to the screen to recover the password, however when I try to reset the password nothing happens and the email cell is marked in red.

What should I do?